# SSL Certificate validation fails in Xamarin Cycle 8 (on Android and iOS)

Tags: wcf, ssl, xamarin

We recently updated our Xamarin tooling to [Cycle 8](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-w-ios-10-and-xcode8-support/).

In routine tests performed after the update, we quickly noted that all HTTPS requests to our WCF-based server component failed.  We still have devices with older versions around, they work fine.  Newly compiled versions all fail to connect.

The connection exceptions always boil down to a `Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException` saying **Invalid certificate received from server** (Error code: 0xffffffff800b010f).

### Investigation

To investigate, we defined a [ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) and looked at the [SslPolicyErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145055(v=vs.110).aspx).  There we noticed that:

- On Android, we always get SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
- On iOS, we always get SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors

We tested this on several domains, the errors were always as listed above.  However, the certificates served by these domains (which you can also see in the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`) were all correct and valid.

I can only assume they are valid because older apps can still connect, because opening these URLs in a browser says the certificate is fine, and because test tools such as [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) give scores of A/A+ for these domains.

### What we tried

A Google search has turned up a few posts suggesting to change the HTTP API that we use.  However, the code connecting to the WCF server is an auto-generated web reference using `ServiceModel.ClientBase` with a `BasicHttpBinding`.  I don't know what HTTP API this is using under the hood, and I don't think that we can easily change it.  Anyway, I would assume that this should work out-of-the-box, as it did until right before the update.

There have been several changes in the TLS API in this Xamarin release cycle.  Some other Xaramin forum posts suggested changing the iOS build options *SSL/TLS implementation* and *HttpClient implementation*.  We tried several permutations of these, but they all yield the same error.  We tried the same with the Android *HttpClient Implementation* setting.  No result.

### Workaround

So for the time being we turned certificate validation off:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += () =>
{
    return true;
};
```

Is there anyone else experiencing this?  Does someone have a solution?  Are we doing something wrong?

### Edit

It's a **bug in Mono.Security**.  See [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44708) for the official bug report.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and workaround as you posted above, it start to happen after the upgrade only. Currently looking into other workarounds. I am using Modern HttpClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Xamarin.iOS Version: 10.0.0.6 Hash: 6c3fee4 Branch: xcode8

The managed HttpClient provider is is broken (again).

#### Workaround:

Under iOS Build, change your **`HttpClient implementation`**:

- from `Managed (default)`
- to **`NSUrlSession (iOS 7+)`**

#### Sample Verification:

```
var webView = new WKWebView(new CGRect(40, 100, 400, 400), new WKWebViewConfiguration());
Add(webView);
var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
button.Frame = new CGRect(40, 40, 100, 40);
Add(button);
button.SetTitle("Fetch", UIControlState.Normal);
button.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://sni.velox.ch");
    webView.LoadHtmlString(new NSString(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()), new NSUrl(""));
};
```

#### `Managed Provider`:

```
TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
```

#### `NSUrlSession (iOS 7+)`:

```
(Successful url fetch)
```

Answer (score 1):

For cross-referencing, a bug has now been filed for this "Invalid certificate received from server" issue for investigation by the Mono team: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44708.

This bug affects Mono, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and Xamarin.Mac.